Calculate correct overall summary revenue in DAX
I have a table of data which I need to create pivot reports from, each line of data is all set out as per example below:

The overall estimated revenue is where my problem is.
This is a figure for the opportunity as a whole not the individual product.
When i put this into a pivot this is the issue i am faced with:

The total should be £97.50 but as each row contains the revenue estimate it is summing it all.
Please could you advise what would be the best way to achieve the result I need. I have loaded all the data into PowerPivot and was hoping a DAX measure would be the best way to go but im struggling with the calculation for what I need to achieve.
Thanks in advance.

Where exactly are you getting that £97.50 from? Sum of none of the columns on your pics sum up to 97.50.

If you see the Revenue Estimate this is for the overall opportunity ID, which multiple lines have the same ID and the same Estimated Revenue. This is the estimate at the opertunity ID level not the product level. The calculation to get to 97.50 is from
£14.50
£50.00
£15.00
£18.00
Which is each line of Estimated Revenue at the opertunity ID level.

I think i need the MAX figure from the opertunity ID which will give me the correct value, any thoughts?

you can try this
Measure 1:=
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( [Overall Opportuntiy Estimated Revenue] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Company] )
)

Measure 2:=
SUMX ( VALUES ( Table1[Company] ), [Measure 1] )



Fantastic ! Thank you so much this is perfect and works just as needed ! Superstar !

Could i ask what the difference would be if i used MAX instead of AVERAGE in measure 1?

max will get the max revenue for each company.
